# Do not share stdin of process started from shell with shell itself

Tags: bash, c, stdin, readline

I'm writing a C program with some shell-like functionalities, among them, running programs in child-processes started over a readline interface in the background.

One problem that I currently have is that as soon as I have spawned such a child process and start typing input characters again, these characters are received by the spawned child process via stdin. This is not too surprising given that I don't modify the children's file descriptors after forking them and I understand that this means that they all share the same stream underlying `STDIN_FILENO` with the main process.

This is, however, not what I intend. I would like my program to behave like e.g. `bash` in this regard such that after re-obtaining a prompt after starting an ongoing process in the background any characters typed on that prompt will only be seen by bash and not by the spawned process. And this is where my problem is because I don't even understand how bash does this. Looking at `/proc/.../fd/0` for `bash` and any spawned processes these always point to the same pseudoterminal. Just redirecting the spawned processes stdin to e.g. `/dev/null` also obviously produces different behavior.

I don't need a complete implementation here, just a general hint.

EDIT: I just figured out that redirecting stdin to `/dev/null` does kind of work if I open `/dev/null` using the `open` command with the `O_RDWR` flag.
My program then seems to behave the way I want except that child processes started this way show up as `<defunct>` when I run `ps`. I'm not sure why this happens.

EDIT: I think I have it figured out now, the easiest way to do this seems to be to create a pseudo terminal slave and then redirect the child's stdin to it:

```
int master;
int slave;

openpty(&master, &slave, nullptr, nullptr, nullptr);

dup2(slave, STDIN_FILENO);
```

Comment: it might be easier to look at how the heirloom bourne shell handles jobs, as that runs to ~800 lines of C code in `jobs.c` versus the ~3,300 in the "too big and too slow" bash

Comment: I will do that. I believe the `<defunct>` was just due to a bug in a thread that waits on children, but looking at a more professional implementation might be a good idea anyways.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so you want to be able to start asynchronous child processes with their input directly connected to /dev/null and that do not become zombies when they die, that on a Unix or Unix-like system.

For the redirection part, the common way is to close the standard input file (file number 0) between the fork and the exec:

```
pid = fork();
if (pid == 0) {        // in child
    close(0);          // close standard input
    execve(...);
}
```

If you do not close files 1 and 2, the output of the child will still go to the terminal. You can close them but any output would be silently discarded...

For the zombie () part, it is enough to ignore the SIGCHLD signal before forking:

```
signal(SIGCHLD, SIG_IGN);
pid = fork();                // this child will never become a zombie process
```

---

References: man fork, man wait, man execve

Comment: I did not think about the second part of your answer so that is helpful. But simple closing stdin does not seem to be the right solution for the redirection part, if I run e.g. `cat &` in a terminal, the spawned process should still have some stdin stream open because `cat` will try to read from it, right? But avoiding zombiefication along with dup'ing stdin to /dev/null should probably do the trick.

Comment: On a second try, both these solutions do not work, closing stdin yields a `Bad file descriptor` error when the program loaded by `execve` tries to read from stdin. But with the `/dev/null` solution e.g. `cat` terminates immediate after all.